# How do I prevent another thread to modify a state flag?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a class

```
class Device
{
    enum State {eStopped, eRunning}
    State flag = eStopped;
public:
    void run(){
        if(flag==eRunning){return;}
        /*some codes to start this device*/
        flag = eRunning;
    }
    void stop(){
        if(flag==eStopped){return;}
        /*some codes to stop this device*/
        flag = eStopped;
    }
    void doMaintenance(){
        if(flag==eRunning){return;} // We can't do maintenance when the device is running
        /*Here, the flag may be modified to eRunning in other threads*/
    }
}
```

In the `doMaintenance()` function, `flag` would be changed by other threads after the `(flag==eRunning)` check. How do I gracefully prevent this happening?

Comment: Do you want to prevent it *completely* or simply make sure reading/writing is synchronized?

Comment: @rustyx std::mutex is to lock a block of same code. In this case, adding mutex for doMaintenance can't help to modify the flag by other functions.

Comment: The only way to not let another function access a variable is to write the code so it doesn't. The C++ language itself (or the standard library) doesn't have any way of preventing variable access, except to make the variable inaccessible to begin with (`private` member access, local variables, or similar language constructs).

Comment: "std::mutex is to lock a block of same code". No, not really.  A mutex doesn't care if it's the same block or not.

Comment: Consider changing the name `run()` to `start()`. The comment in the code says, "some codes to _start_ this device." If that's how you describe what it does, then the name should be "start()".

Comment: @SolomonSlow, yes, indeed. I had focused on locking of modification of the flag. It turns out that I should lock the modification of the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are other problems to solve as well. For example, suppose that the device is in a stopped state. Then, in two threads, you execute `run()`. Then two threads start to execute the same starting sequence. We should take care of this as well.

So, the simplest solution is to not allow any of the `run()`, `stop()` and `doMaintenance()` to run concurrently. This can be easily solved by a mutex:

```
class Device
{
    enum State {eStopped, eRunning}
    State flag = eStopped;
    std::mutex m_mutex;
public:
    void run(){
        std::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex);
        if(flag==eRunning){return;}
        /*some codes to start this device*/
        flag = eRunning;
    }
    void stop(){
        std::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex);
        if(flag==eStopped){return;}
        /*some codes to stop this device*/
        flag = eStopped;
    }
    void doMaintenance(){
        std::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex);
        if(flag==eRunning){return;} // We can't do maintenance when the device is running
        /*Here, the flag may be modified to eRunning in other threads*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys, including ones in the comments. Additional, I had tried lock_guard in run() and start() and m_mutex.try_lock() in doMaintenance() yesterday. Because I don't want doMaintenance to wait, just return when it is locked. It works well. But I wonder if there is a std::try_lock() to instead of mutex::try_lock(). I found there was std::try_lock(). But it takes 2 parameters. I don't know why. And what's the difference between lock_guard and scoped_lock?